# php_value in .htaccess show Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, error-handling

I add This line for handeling error into `txt` files in `.htaccess` :

```
php_value  log_errors on
php_value error_log /hermes/bosoraweb114/b2947/arcom/cms/cache/logs/errorser.txt
```

But in action my page I see : `Internal Server Error`

When i remove this two lines my page worked. How do can i fix this problem?

Comment: take sure folder for error_log exisits and is wirteable

Comment: Please explain what you want to achieve? Do you want to save the log_errors in errorser.txt file?

Comment: please try my solution, it may solve problem, once i had same problem replace `.txt` to `\.txt`

Answer (score 1):

You need to determine if PHP is setup in CGI mode. If it is you cannot add those lines to your .htaccess file. You will need to make your changes via php.ini

Check this link for how to check if PHP is CGI or APACHE: https://www.opensource-excellence.com/blog/item/416-how-to-determine-php-is-running-as-php-cgi-or-apache-module?.html

Answer (score -1):

correct your code

```
php_value  log_errors on
php_value error_log /hermes/bosoraweb114/b2947/arcom/cms/cache/logs/errorser\.txt
```